# findAll sequelize with model returning odd values

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

*Solved thanks to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64702949/14585149*

I am looking to list all transactions I have on a mysql database with the associated users.

I have 2 tables / models : **Transaction** & **User**

Transaction :

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('transactions', {
    transaction_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'users',
        key: 'user_id'
      }
    },
    account_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'accounts',
        key: 'account_id'
      }
    },




 }, { tableName: 'transactions' }); };
```

User :

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('users', {
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'recipients',
        key: 'created_by'
      }
    },
    contact_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'contacts',
        key: 'contact_id'
      }
    }, }, {
    tableName: 'users',
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

I have made the associations :

```
Transaction.hasOne(User, {foreignKey:'user_id'});
User.belongsTo(Transaction, {foreignKey:'user_id'});
```

and my code is :

```
api.get('/trx', async (req, res) => {

   
  Transaction.findAll({
    attributes: ['transaction_id','user_id','account_id'],
    include: [{
      model: User,
      attributes: ['user_id']}]

  })
  .then(intrx => res.json(intrx))
  
  .catch(res.catch_error)


});
```

the result :

```
[
  {
    "transaction_id": 1,
    "user_id": 4,
    "account_id": 1,
    "user": {
      "user_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "transaction_id": 2,
    "user_id": 4,
    "account_id": 75,
    "user": {
      "user_id": 2
    }
  }
]
```

why the values of user_id are different ?
I am expecting the user_id = 4 instead of 1 in my first result and user_id = 4 in my second result.

what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Show model definitions. I don't get it either `Transaction` has `user_id` field or `User`

Comment: I have added the 2 models to the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

You should reverse your associations like this:

```
Transaction.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey:'user_id'});
User.hasOne(Transaction, {foreignKey:'user_id'});
```

because `Transaction` has link to `User` i.e. belongs to it.